# Problems trying to keep SSH session alive "forever"

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, debian, openssh, sshd

I know there are many questions/articles about this topic. But... I tried a bunch of them and nothing seems to make my SSH connection alive "forever".

I'm currently working from MacOs BigSur and coding via SSH (terminal - iTerm2) on a Virtual Machine (server - Debian). What's the problem? From time to time (sometimes more, sometimes less time) **the screen freezes and after a few seconds it disconnects from the VM and it shows "client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe".** I know there is stuff like mosh, but that's not the solution I'm looking.

**Note:** my VM is local

I tried a bunch of different stuff, both on Host OS and Server. **This is what my configs currently have:**

Host ( ~/.ssh/config )

```
Host <name>
    HostName <ip>
    User <VM username>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    ServerAliveInterval 86400
    TCPKeepAlive yes
```

VM - Server Debian ( /etc/ssh/sshd_config )

```
ClientAliveInterval 86400
```

If someone needs any other information that is in sshd_config please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Why are yoyr AluveIbtervaks do high? Try changing them to 60 and they may actually do something.

Comment: @davigo My AliveIntervals? To try keep alive the connection "forever". Isn't that their function? Btw, I already tried lower values, like 300

Comment: Do you know how these options work exactly? See [this answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585887/108618) and the links therein. This may not help you solve the current problem immediately but you will be informed about the purpose of the options you're using. Being informed is a good thing.

Comment: @DGF I dont believe they work the way you think.  Rather ai believe these will send "ping" packets every X seconds of inactivity to keep the TCP session alive.  They are not an inactivity timeout as your settings would imply.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm not sure but think I understand: its the interval of time in which is send some type of "request" to verify that everything is "ok" with the other side, something like that. If I place a higher value it shouldn't send nothing for long period of time therefore connection not being close if there was any problem in either side for some seconds? But, either way, I tried lower values and that didn't solve my problem. Maybe something related to firewall of MacOs?